# Voltage divider on differential op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

I need to measure the voltage across the R2 (VA - VB) but it is above the common mode voltage range of op-amp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOa8HQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How could I do that? I was thinking of a second voltage divider across the R2, but that would affect the gain of the op-amp and I don't think I can analyse it. Though, I reckon that is not a good practise.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg5fDt.png)</sup>

Then, I thought of using two voltage dividers in each point (VA, VB). But this would also affect the gain of the op-amp

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcrAIS.png)</sup>

Finally, I'm guessing this is the best way I can think of.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwTnUd.png)</sup>

V1 could vary from 24V to 30V. The ratio of voltage dividers is arbitary taken. I just wanted to show the circuit.
Is it a good circuit? Is there anything better I can do?

Comment: Anything better? Choose an InAmp with the ability to deal with the common mode voltage of 12 volts. There are a few. Try analogue devices, Texas etc..

Comment: From the information you provide it's unclear what you are trying to achieve. If you want to know the voltage, why not take a multimeter and measure?

Comment: @Andyaka I've seen multimeters use voltage dividers to handle high voltages when they measure. I could indeed choose an InAmp with high Vcm but what would I do if I wanted to use the same circuit in higher voltages?

Comment: You would make R6 and R4 very much lower in value.

Comment: What would I get if I made R6 and R4 very much lower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXTK6i.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Va= 12V, Vin+=6V exceeds Vcm range thus output is saturated near  Vs=3.3V thus Vcm >= 3.3V is a violation and Vout saturated is outside linear range where output stays saturated with small changes of input which as we know if transfer function ΔVo/Vin= 0= gain is a violation of linear mode or "non-linear"

The 2nd example reduces the current sensor R-value to try to operate in the linear range.

**other details**

Although input impedances are mismatched 100 Ohms vs 100k, is a -60dB CM error comparable to 100k 0.1% error of also -60dB CM error per pair or -57dB worse case.

This will never be as good as INA's with 120 dB CMRR at 10Hz. In both cases decreases by open loop gain at a closed-loop gain =1 .

The same is true for cables.  The impedance imbalance increases with frequency and 120 Ohm cables but they will never be as well matched as a DIFF AMP so the cable CMRR "can be" a problem resolved with very low source impedance and singe ended shields. For RF,  Baluns or Pi filters are also added to reject Vcm E-field noise on a long inductive cable at low f due to differential inductance error and induced currents.